# Default message in botman

Tags: laravel, chatbot

I'm testing botman in Laravel and it works very well. But I can not find how to put a message by default. Can someone give me an orientation ?

```
$botman->hears('Hi', function ($bot) {
    $bot->reply('Hello!');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BotMan allows you to create a fallback method, that gets called if none of your "hears" patterns matches. You may use this feature to give your bot users guidance on how to use your bot.

```
$botman->fallback(function($bot) {
$bot->reply('Sorry, I did not understand these commands. Here is a list of commands I understand: ...');
```

});